# Change images using Jquery (Circular motion)

Tags: jquery, click, image, src, attr

Good day guys,

I've a DOM like this

```
<div class="Gallery">
  <div class="GaleryLeftPanel">
     <img id="img1" src="/Content/Public/images/1.png" style="z-index: 100" width="141"
                            height="140" alt="image 1" /></div>
   <div class="GalleryMiddlePanel">
      <img id="img2" src="/Content/Public/images/3.png" style="z-index: 99" width="715"
                            height="497" alt="image 2" /></div>
   <div class="GaleryRightPanel">
      <img id="img3" src="/Content/Public/images/2.png" style="z-index: 98" width="140"
                            height="140" alt="image 2" /></div>
 </div>
```

What I need is, If I click on **img1**, *img2 is replaced with img1*, and *img3 is replaced with img2* and *img1 is replaced with img3* (circular motion 1->2, 2->3, 3->1). and it continuous... and if I click on img3 then it's reverse (1<-2, 2<-3, 3<-1).

for this I'm using JQuery as follows:

```
$('img#img1').click(function () {
        var currentScr = $(this).attr('src');
        var second = $('img#img2').attr('src');
        var third = $('img#img3').attr('src');

        $('img#img3').attr('src', second);
        $('img#img2').attr('src', currentScr);
        $('img#img1').attr('src', third);
    });

    $('img#img3').click(function () {
        var third = $(this).attr('src');
        var first = $('img#img1').attr('src');
        var second = $('img#img2').attr('src');

        $('img#img2').attr('src', third);
        $('img#img3').attr('src', first);
        $('img#img1').attr('src', second);
    });
```

It's working fine. now, What I need is, Always the 2nd image should be replace with large image instead of original image... say for example:

click on img1 (**1->2L**, 2->3, 3->1). here 2L is large image of img1. and 
click on img3 (1<-2, 2L<-3, 3<-1). here 2L is large image of img3

How to do this?, Please help me

Comment: Can't you just call for the 2L image ? It being big or not doesn't change anything to the logic, especially if its a both ways need.

Comment: could you make a fiddle .. ?

Comment: @jonBreizh Ya i tried that. thing is, If I click on img1 second time, src of img2 will be set to src of img3, so, img3 src will get that larger image instead of original image

Comment: @AatishMolasi http://jsfiddle.net/6HHkT/

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve visually ? My guess is you are missing a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is to use a double ended queue data structure so you can loop through the images.

Here's [a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/6HHkT/2/) - if you give me URLs to the big images I can make it work as you described.

And here's the code:

```
var imgs = new Array();
imgs[0] = 'http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6198/6145108610_a5d456dae4_t.jpg';
imgs[1] = 'http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2564/4064894944_34b0460fc2_t.jpg';
imgs[2] = 'http://farm1.staticflickr.com/178/460793430_1c0a085849_t.jpg';

$('#img1').click(function () {
        $('#img1').attr('src', imgs[2]);
        $('#img2').attr('src', imgs[0]); // - Do something here to use a larger version of the image
        $('#img3').attr('src', imgs[1]);
        imgs.unshift(imgs.pop());
    });

    $('#img3').click(function () {
        $('#img1').attr('src', imgs[1]);
        $('#img2').attr('src', imgs[2]); // - Do something here to use a larger version of the image
        $('#img3').attr('src', imgs[0]);
        imgs.push(imgs.shift());
});
```

And a slightly refactored version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/6HHkT/3/).

**EDIT:**

And here's [a version with big images.](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/6HHkT/5/)

```
var imgs = new Array();
imgs[0] = {small: 'http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6198/6145108610_a5d456dae4_t.jpg',
           big: 'http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6198/6145108610_a5d456dae4_b.jpg'};
imgs[1] = {small: 'http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2564/4064894944_34b0460fc2_t.jpg',
           big: 'http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2564/4064894944_34b0460fc2_b.jpg'};
imgs[2] = {small: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8201/8219867682_7c9aea748f_t.jpg',
           big: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8201/8219867682_7c9aea748f_b.jpg'};

var $img1 = $('#img1');
var $img2 = $('#img2');
var $img3 = $('#img3');

$img1.click(function () {
    $img1.attr('src', imgs[2].small);
    $img2.attr('src', imgs[0].big);
    $img3.attr('src', imgs[1].small);
    imgs.unshift(imgs.pop());
});

$img3.click(function () {
    $img1.attr('src', imgs[1].small);
    $img2.attr('src', imgs[2].big);
    $img3.attr('src', imgs[0].small);
    imgs.push(imgs.shift());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're trying to have gallery with middle picture in the high resolution.

I checked the flickr from where you took pics, and the rule seems:

- big pic: http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6198/6145108610_a5d456dae4_b.jpg
- small pic: http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6198/6145108610_a5d456dae4_t.jpg

so they differ in `_t` / `_b` only.

To implement it I updated your js part like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var second = $('img#img2').attr('src');
    $('img#img2').attr('src', swap(second));   
});

function swap(img) {   
    if (img.indexOf("_b.") !== -1) {
    return img.replace("_b.", "_t.");
    } else {
    return img.replace("_t.", "_b.");
    }    
}

$('img#img1').click(function () {
    var currentScr = $(this).attr('src');
    var second = $('img#img2').attr('src');
    var third = $('img#img3').attr('src');

    $('img#img3').attr('src', swap(second));
    $('img#img2').attr('src', swap(currentScr));
    $('img#img1').attr('src', third);
    });

    $('img#img3').click(function () {
    var third = $(this).attr('src');
    var first = $('img#img1').attr('src');
    var second = $('img#img2').attr('src');

    $('img#img2').attr('src', swap(third));
    $('img#img3').attr('src', first);
    $('img#img1').attr('src', swap(second));
});
```

Moreover (to see resolution change I made pics a bit bigger): 140/141 -> 300

jsfille link: http://jsfiddle.net/dx3DY/

Only thing seems to be that one of the sample pics doesn't seem to be in the high resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the larger images for each image say `1L.png, 2L.png, 3L.png` and change your script as follows:

```
$('img#img1').click(function () {
        var currentScr = $(this).attr('src');
        var second = $('img#img2').attr('src');
        var third = $('img#img3').attr('src');

        $('img#img3').attr('src', second.replace('1L', '1').replace('2L', '2').replace('3L', '3'));
        $('img#img2').attr('src', currentScr.replace('1', '1L').replace('2', '2L').replace('3', '3L'));
        $('img#img1').attr('src', third);
    });

    $('img#img3').click(function () {
        var third = $(this).attr('src');
        var first = $('img#img1').attr('src');
        var second = $('img#img2').attr('src');

        $('img#img2').attr('src', third.replace('1', '1L').replace('2', '2L').replace('3', '3L'));
        $('img#img3').attr('src', first);
        $('img#img1').attr('src', second.replace('1L', '1').replace('2L', '2').replace('3L', '3'));
    });
```