# changing the image in jquery

Tags: jquery, image, src

this is my html

```
<a href="/name/nm3515425/?ref_=tt_cl_i1"><img height="44" width="32" alt="Ross Lynch" title="Ross Lynch" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/G/01/imdb/images/nopicture/32x44/name-2138558783._V379389446_.png" class="loadlate hidden " loadlate="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjYyODA4ODcyOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDk4NDg4OQ@@._V1_SY44_CR1,0,32,44_.jpg"></a>
```

i want to change the src image to loadlate 
i tried searching but i didn't get my answer

Comment: This question has been answered several times before (like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563804/change-images-using-jquery-circular-motion). Try searching before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(img_id).attr("src","new_url")
```

Answer (score 0):

First use **data-*** attribute instead of your own. Change your attribute to something like that:

```
data-loadlate="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjYyODA4ODcyOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDk4NDg4OQ@@._V1_SY44_CR1,0,32,44_.jpg"
```

Second use this for change src with value from your attribute:

```
var img = $(a img);
img.attr("src", img.attr('data-loadlate'));
```